# Break not Stopping Simple While Loop Python

Tags: python, while-loop, break

Python noob here. I am trying to create a list with numbers a user inputs and then do some simple calculations with the numbers in the list at the end, in a while loop. The While loop is not breaking when 'done' is inputted. It just prints 'Invalid input.'

```
list = []
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        list.append(n)
    except:
        print('Invalid input') 
    if n == 'done':
        break

print(sum.list())
print(len.list())
print(mean.list())
```

Comment: The only way any value gets assigned to `n` is after applying `int()` to the user's input.  There is no conceivable return value from `int()` that is equal to `'done'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to separate receiving user input with checking against "done" from conversion to a number and appending to the list. And you will have to check for "done" before converting the input to an integer.

Try something like this:

```
list_of_numbers = []

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a number or 'done' to end: ")

    if user_input == "done":
        break

    try:
        number = int(user_input)

    except ValueError:
        print("invalid number")
        continue

    list_of_numbers.append(number)

print(list_of_numbers)

# further processing of the list here
```

Comment: I like this approach however, I am getting an AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'list'.

Comment: @antman well, this likely comes from some further processing on your part. I suspect you're doing `something.list` somewhere and **something** doesn't have a **list** attribute.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to print(sum.list()) instead of print(sum(list))....noob working late...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the int() function is trying to convert your input into an integer, but it is raising an error because the string 'done' can not be converted to an integer. Another point is that sum(), mean() and len() are functions, not attributes of [lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp). Also mean() is not a built in function in python, it must be import with [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html). Try it like this:

```
from numpy import mean
list = []
while True:
    try:
        n = input('Enter a number: ')
        list.append(int(n))
    except:
        if n!='done':
            print('Invalid input') 
    if n == 'done':
        break

print(sum(list))
print(len(list))
print(mean(list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You must check if you can turn the input into a integer before appending to your list. You can use use the try/except to catch if the input variable is convertible to a integer. If it's not then you can check for `done` and exit.

```
list = []
while True:
    n = input('Enter a number: ')
    try:
        n = int(n)
        list.append(n)
    except ValueError:
        if n == 'done':
            break
        print('Invalid input') 

total = sum(list)
length = len(list)
mean = total/length

print('sum:', total)
print('length:', length)
print('mean:', mean)
```

Example interaction

```
Enter a number: 12
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number:
Invalid input
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number:
Invalid input
Enter a number: done
sum: 24
length: 4
mean: 6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters `done`, you will attempt to convert into an `int`, which will raise an exception that you then catch.

Instead, perform your check **before** attempting to convert it to an integer.